# Request hangs on pending in express

Tags: express

I have the following in express:

```
app.post('/template-preview', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`here is req: ${req}`);
    res.send('it was hit');
    res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
});
```

I then make the following call using Axios:

```
const getPreviewTemplate = async () => {
  console.log('in get previewtemplate')
  const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/template-preview',
  {firstName: 'frank', lastName: 'gomez'}
);
  result.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  return result;
}
```

I can confirm the following works because I get the console.log('in get previewtemplate');
However after that it hangs.  When I go to my network tab in chrome I see "pending" for the request. It stays like that.

I have this to handle cors in my express code before the route.  Not sure if this is causing the issue:  `app.use(cors);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also can't do this:  `console.log(\`here is req: ${req}\`);`.  Change that to  `console.log('here is req:', req);`.  And, you can't call both `res.send()` and `res.render()`.  Each tries to send a separate response to the incoming request and you only get one response per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes here.  It's hard to know for sure which one is causing your problem since you offer us no diagnostics at all other than "it hangs".

First, `getPreviewTemplate()` has NO error handling at all.  If your `axios.post()` rejects, you have no code for logging it.

Second, `const result = await axios.post()` returns an actual result, NOT a promise.  So, you can't do `result.then()` on it.

Third, `console.log(\`here is req: ${req}`);`won't help you because that will try to convert req to a string which will probably just be "[Object object]".  Instead, you need to do:` console.log('here is req: ', req);`so you pass the whole object to`console.log()` and let it use its display smarts to show the object.

Fourth, `app.use(cors);` is supposed to be `app.use(cors());` and that very well could be why every request gets stuck since `next()` never gets called.

Fifth, you only get to send one response for each incoming request so trying to do both `res.send()` and `res.render()` is just wrong.  Pick one or the other, not both.

To summarize:

Change this:

```
app.use(cors)
```

to this:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Change this:

```
app.post('/template-preview', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`here is req: ${req}`);
    res.send('it was hit');
    res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
});
```

to this:

```
app.post('/template-preview', (req, res) => {
    console.log('here is req: ', req);
    res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
});
```

Change this:

```
const getPreviewTemplate = async () => {
  console.log('in get previewtemplate')
  const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/template-preview',
  {firstName: 'frank', lastName: 'gomez'}
);
  result.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  return result;
}
```

to this:

```
const getPreviewTemplate = async () => {
  console.log('in get previewtemplate')
  const result = await axios.post(
      'http://localhost:5000/template-preview',
      {firstName: 'frank', lastName: 'gomez'}
  );
  console.log(result);
  // this will be the resolved value of the promise
  // that this async function returns
  return result;
}
```

Then, whoever is calling `getPreviewTemplate()` will get back a promise and will have to use either `await` or `.then()` on the promise they get back to get your actual result.

Answer (score 1):

this is really common if you are not parsing the json correctly. make sure in your server file you use.

`server.use(express.json())`

If you already have this make sure it is in the correct place as it is read top down so position matters.